# Unit tests and mocking for each test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Sometimes in my test I need to perform a different Setup() call that sets up Mocks differently for each test run - like so:

```
private void Setup(bool isTrue)
{
    mock.Setup(x => x.DisplayNames).Returns(new Dictionary<int, string>());
    // ...
    // 5x more of these are the same for all tests

    if (isTrue)
      mock.Setup(x => x.DisplayOld).Returns(isTrue);
      // 5x more of these parameterlized setups 
      ...
}
```

Now, in each of my unit tests I would make a call to Setup(true/false).

Since unit tests are running in parallel (xUnit by default), will this cause any locking issues? (Suppose two tests call Setup() at the same time).

If that is the case:

1. how to rectify this situation?
2. what is the proper approach if one wants to have a single method (like setup()) with a parameter passed - for different mocking scenarios?

Comment: If your `Setup` method is being automatically called by your unit testing framework, then yes, you will have problems. If it is actually called by your tests, then it should be fine, assuming that A) the mocked objects are not being stored statically (for example, in an object factory), and B), the mocked objects are not setup using shared functionality (for example: `.Returns(myDictionarySharedBetweenTests)`.

Comment: Rob, can you please clarify? Yes, I am calling setup() from each of my tests [Fact] method. and it's a simple setup like in the code above-where nothing is shared. Simply different setup scenarios based on bool flag ex: mock.Setup(x => x.DoSomething).Returns(true) / false etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check the article about the [Test Context](http://blog.roboblob.com/2014/01/16/introducing-the-unit-testing-context-pattern/) pattern. You can have mocks as local variables and customize their setup in the test context class. Then it's safe to run them in parallel. I use this pattern in Java with JUnit+Mockito and in .Net with NUnit/MSTest+Moq.

Comment: this still doesn't solve the problem of setting up mocks (the same way) 10 times and setting up only 1 mock differently based on parameter. You end up with 10x ctx.SomeMock.Setup()

Comment: Usually I have a method like PerformDefaultSetup() in TestContext. This way I don't have to repeat the same setup in test methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the parameterized unit testing. InlineData attribute of xUnit test framework can be used. The mock doesn't need to be set in the setup method in this case. It can  be set directly in the actual test method. Your test method would look like below

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(false)]
[InlineData(true)]
public void SampleTest(bool flag)
{
    .... //do any set up operations
    .... //Assert logic to verify
}
```

The test framework will generate as many test methods at run-time based on the input you provide with the InlineData attribute. Since the test method is split into separate methods at run-time, you would not get into any locking or threading issues.

Comment: that's not feasible..I would have bunch of duplicate code for 10x moq setups and only one that changes with parameter.

Comment: It could be still possible @ShaneKm. You can write the common code in a separate method and call that method from your test method.